# Red/White wine at the Seder

Tags: halacha, minhag, passover, color, four-cups-wine

Is there any Halacha or Minhag that specifies if red or White wine should be used for the four cups of wine during the Passover seder and does it matter what you use to spill out during the 10 plagues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not only it is a Minhag, those who say Yotzros on Shabbos Hagadol say it in there:

> יין  כי יתאדם למצוה הוא מקדם

Translates as "Wine that is Red for the Mitzvah ahead" Not only that the Rambam says you are not Yotzeh using white wine for kiddush (we do not rule like that) and the [Mishnah Berurah](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%90) adds Pesach there is another reason to remind us of the  of the blood of the Jewish children Pharaoh used to Bathe in.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could point me to the source of Rambam, I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Kazibácsi Maybe he meant to say "... _that the Ramba**n** says you are not Yotzeh using white wine for kiddush_ ...", As [Shulchan Arukh Orach Chayim 272:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.272.4?lang=bi&lang2=en) says: "מקדשין על יין לבן, **והרמב"ן פוסלו לקידוש אפילו בדיעבד**, אבל מבדילים עליו, ומנהג העולם כסברא ראשונה" ("Kiddush may be recited over white wine, **but the Ramban disqualifies it even after the fact**. But we may recite havdalah on it. The custom of the world is like the first opinion.")

Comment: @Tamir א גרויסע שכוייח!

Answer (score 7):

Dittos to YS. The reason that many Ashkenazim stopped using red wine for the seder is because of the blood libels, but today (unless you live in an Arabic country) this is not a concern and therefore it is preferable to use red wine for the four cups at the seder.

Comment: Note the word "preferable", not "required."  Remind me again please, if you personally like white wine more, or the white you have is higher quality than the red, is that enough to overcome the Halachic preference for red?

Comment: Based on the Rambam I would say yes

Comment: Based on the Shulchan Aruch I would say no.

Comment: pour a few drops of merlot in your chardonnay just so it looks red without affecting the taste too much. Or maybe it will.

Answer (score -1):

The Rav, Rabbi Joseph Ber Solovetchik, says to have red wine for the first cup [Kiddush], to signify Cherut (≈freedom).

Comment: Interesting. Can you cite where he says this?