# Why does the Jerusalem Talmud speak of only white wine grapes being offered at the temple?

Tags: grapes-wine, talmud-yerushalmi, bikkurim-first-fruits

According to Asaph Goor, the Jerusalem Talmud, Bikkurim, chapter 1, Halacha 3, contains a discussion on the question of the propriety of vine offerings to the Temple. It strictly enjoins that only choice and sound grapes from white grape varietals were allowed ... free from plant disease or insect pest, and untreated by spraying or dusting:

> One does not offer grapes that have been smoked or
> dusted. One brings white grapes and grapes of good quality.

After the fall of the Temple, and the expulsion of so many of its Jews from Israel, vineyards were abandoned and destroyed:

> Formerly grapes were
> plentiful...nowadays there are not many (Jerusalem Talmud, Damai,
> Chapter 1, Halacha 1).

How does this question compare to that of [why red wine is prescribed for the seder?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/125545/why-is-red-wine-prescribed-for-seder-and-what-does-it-represent)

*The question was based upon my reading of: "The History of the Grape-Vine in the Holy Land"
Author(s): Asaph Goor
Source: Economic Botany , Jan. - Mar., 1966, Vol. 20, No. 1 (Jan. - Mar., 1966), pp. 46-64. Published by: Springer on behalf of New York Botanical Garden Press Stable URL: https://www.jstor.org/stable/4252702*

Comment: Maybe its because they only sacrificed plant foods.

Comment: Could you unpack that thought some more?

Comment: As you seem to have copied most of the body of your question from ["The History of the Grape-Vine in the Holy Land" by Asaph Goor in _Economic Botany_ (p.53)](https://archive.org/details/Goor19651967FiveFruits/page/n21/mode/2up), why not give it it's due credit?

Comment: (1) On the one hand, all the sources, quoted in the linked question, requiring/suggesting red wine seem to be post-Talmudic. (2) On the other hand, In the [Mishneh Torah Hilkhot Bikurim 2:3](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1002528/jewish/Bikkurim-Chapter-2.htm#v3) (which discusses not bringing dusty and smoked grapes) doesn't mention the grapes having to be white. (3) Also, can we confirm "[הענבים הלבלונית](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Bikkurim.3a.1?lang=bi&lang2=he)" actually means "white grapes"?

Comment: Tamir, excellent observations! I have updated my question to reflect Asaph Goor's article that I got the observation from. I did not do primary research into whether he was correct or not.